# elasticsearch custom analyzer by specific chracter

Tags: elasticsearch

How to create custom analyzer that tokenize a field by '/' characters only.

I have url strings in my field for exp: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
I want tokenized this like: "http", "stackoverflow.com", "questions" and "ask"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you want, using a [pattern tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html):

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "slash_analyzer": {
               "type": "pattern",
               "pattern": "[/:]+",
               "lowercase": true
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "url": {
               "type": "string",
               "index_analyzer": "slash_analyzer",
               "search_analyzer": "standard",
               "term_vector": "yes"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
   "url": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
}
```

I added [term vectors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html) in the mapping (you probably don't want to do this in production), so we can see what terms are generated:

```
GET /test_index/doc/1/_termvector
...
{
   "_index": "test_index",
   "_type": "doc",
   "_id": "1",
   "_version": 1,
   "found": true,
   "took": 1,
   "term_vectors": {
      "url": {
         "field_statistics": {
            "sum_doc_freq": 4,
            "doc_count": 1,
            "sum_ttf": 4
         },
         "terms": {
            "ask": {
               "term_freq": 1
            },
            "http": {
               "term_freq": 1
            },
            "questions": {
               "term_freq": 1
            },
            "stackoverflow.com": {
               "term_freq": 1
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/669fbdd681895d7e9f8db13799865c6e8be75b11

Answer (score 0):

The standard analyzer already does that for you.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze?analyzer=standard&pretty' -d 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'
```

You get this:

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "http",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 4,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "stackoverflow.com",
    "start_offset" : 7,
    "end_offset" : 24,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 2
  }, {
    "token" : "questions",
    "start_offset" : 25,
    "end_offset" : 34,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 3
  }, {
    "token" : "ask",
    "start_offset" : 35,
    "end_offset" : 38,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 4
  } ]
}
```

Comment: for this case ok. but standart analyzer tokenize string by '.' character also which I don't want..

Comment: If you look at the second token `stackoverflow.com`, you'll see that the "." is still part of the token.

Comment: yeah but some url strings contains other characters may cause tokenize by standard analyzer " , : ;" etc.. I just want to split it by '/'.